# AWS SAM Deploy, how to find URL of API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, sam

**How do I find the URL address of the API Gateway after deployment from Command line ?**

I use a script similar to below to deploy my API Gateway and Authorizer, and it deploys fine.

`https://github.com/floodfx/aws-lambda-proxy-using-sam-local/blob/master/deploy.sh`

**I'm trying to figure out how to get the address of the API Gateway after Deployment from the command line**

The API Gateway gets created, I can see the stack:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks
```

```
"Stacks": [
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:761861444952:stack/mygateway912/72100720-6e67-11e8-93e9-500c28604c4a", 
            "Description": "An example serverless \"Hello World2 \" application with a custom authorizer.", 
            "Tags": [], 
            "CreationTime": "2018-06-12T17:38:40.946Z", 
            "Capabilities": [
                "CAPABILITY_IAM"
            ], 
            "StackName": "mygateway912", 
            "NotificationARNs": [], 
            "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
            "DisableRollback": false, 
            "ChangeSetId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:76161444952:changeSet/awscli-cloudformation-package-deploy-1528825120/352f7c7a-2870-44ea-9e7f-40d16c0015df", 
            "LastUpdatedTime": "2018-06-12T17:38:46.411Z"
        }
```

There must be a simple command I'm missing to get this.

Comment: you can use output parameter of the cloudformation template to export resource references

Comment: I just saw that.. Maybe it will help someone else I'll add an example

Comment: Outputs:

  ExampleAPIUrl:
    Value: !Sub "https://${ExampleAPI}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${StageName}/"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just had time to answer properly. Having API Gateway definition:

```
Resources:
  ...
  ServerlessRestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    DeletionPolicy: "Retain"
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
  ...
```

you can output

```
Outputs:
  ProdDataEndpoint:
    Description: "API Prod stage endpoint"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

Comment: I put some example on my github, if anyone is still struggling with this: https://github.com/pmcdowell-okta/my-notes/tree/master/awsSam

Comment: How can I get the value of that output at runtime?

Answer (score 11):

I have separate `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` and `AWS::ApiGateway::Stage` resources, so my Output looked a bit different, since I didn't/couldn't hard code the stage name:

```
Outputs:
  ProdEndpoint:
    Value: !Sub "https://${ApiGw}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${ApiGwStage}/"

Resources:
  ApiGw:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: 'Serverless Ipsum #noServerNovember challenge'
      FailOnWarnings: true

  ApiGwDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    # Required -- see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-deployment.html
    DependsOn: ApiGwMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGw

  ApiGwStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      DeploymentId: !Ref ApiGwDeployment
      MethodSettings:
        - DataTraceEnabled: true
          HttpMethod: '*'
          LoggingLevel: INFO
          ResourcePath: '/*'
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGw
      StageName: prod

  ApiGwResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGw
      ParentId: !GetAtt ["ApiGw", "RootResourceId"]
      PathPart: "{proxy+}"

  ApiGwMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGw
      ResourceId: !Ref ApiGwResource
      HttpMethod: ANY
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${ServerlessIpsumFunction.Arn}/invocations"
```

Comment: Op specified SAM Deploy (not explicitly creating resources).

Answer (score 0):

I am using a parameter `AppEnv`

```yaml
....

Parameters:
  ...

  AppEnv:
    Type: String
    Default: stage
    Description: Application environment

Resources:
  GateWayAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Ref AppEnv
      ....
  UploadFileFunction:
    ....
      Events:
        UploadFile:
          ...
          Properties:
            Path: /upload-file
            Method: post
            RestApiId: !Ref GateWayAPI
....

Outputs:
 ....
  UploadFileApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for UploadFileFunction"
    Value: !Sub "https://${GateWayAPI}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${AppEnv}/upload-file/"
  ...
```

Full configuration [file](https://github.com/vanduc1102/samples/blob/master/aws/java-lambda-s3/template.yaml)